# Accessing Lambda Layer within Python subprocess

Tags: python, aws-lambda, subprocess, aws-lambda-layers

I'm having issues accessing my custom python modules that are in a lambda layer from within a python subprocess. My use case is thus:

I have a large custom module with many dependencies defined in a lambda layer (which I will call `myCustomModule.py`). I allow arbitrary code to be uploaded as a lambda function in a file called `function.py`. That script gets called in a subprocess in `app.py`, which contains the handler that Lambda calls.

myCustomModule.py

```
def printFoo():
   print("foo")
```

function.py

```
import myCustomModule

myCustomModule.printFoo()
```

app.py

```
import subprocess

def handler(event, context):
    functionFilePath = "function.py"
    return subprocess.check_output("python3 " + functionFilePath, shell=True)
```

When I execute the lambda function, it returns a `ModuleNotFoundError` saying function.py cannot find myCustomModule. However, if I import myCustomModule in app.py and call `printFoo()` from there, it works fine. However, that breaks my use case because I need to be able to call myCustomModule from function.py, and not app.py.

How can I get the python subprocess to recognize modules in my lambda layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I needed to do two things:

First I needed to add the location to my module from my lambda layer to my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

[image]

Next, I needed to increase the memory and timeout size of the function, since my module was pretty large:
[image]

You can do this either in the Lambda console, with the AWS CLI or with the AWS SDK (I'm using the Java SDK).